# Data Exporter for PrimeFaces Extensions Sheet

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions

How can i export data in PrimeFaces Extensions Sheet like PrimeFaces DataTable?
I tried PrimeFaces DataTable exporter like below but it doesn't support sheet table.

```html
<p:commandButton value="XLS" styleClass="mr-2 mb-2">
    <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="mainForm:sheet" fileName="department"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

It throws `org.primefaces.extensions.component.sheet.Sheet cannot be cast to org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable` exception. How can I use data exporter for PrimeFaces Extensions Sheet.

JSF: 2.2.1, PrimeFaces: 12.0.0, PrimeFaces Extensions: 12.0.5

Answer (score 1):

As the exception shows, and what the [documentation](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/12_0_0/#/components/dataexporter) states, `p:dataExporter` "must point to a PrimeFaces `DataTable`".

As [`Sheet`](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/primefaces/extensions/component/sheet/SheetBase.java) does not extend `DataTable`, `p:dataExporter` will not work with it.

Options to get it working are:

1. Refactor `Sheet` to extend `DataTable`. I did not investigate this, and do not know if this is possible at all.
2. Create an exporter for sheets.

You could create an [issue](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions/issues) to request export support for sheets. It would be even better if you would provided a pull request with it.

Comment: Issue created: https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions/issues/1156